# Angular .json() force lowercase translation

Tags: json, angular

*Environment:* ASP.NET MVC Core with Angular

After several hours of troubleshooting it appears the issue I'm encountering is that the Angular.json() function needs my classes to be in specific notation.

**ASP.NET Model**

```
public class ElementProperty
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ElementId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**ASP.NET Controller**

```
// GET: api/ElementProperties
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<ElementProperty> GetElementProperties()
{
    return _context.ElementProperties;
}
```

**Angular Component**

You would think this Component would work.

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'ElementProperty',
    templateUrl: './ElementPropertyComponent.html'
})
export class ElementPropertyComponent {
    public Properties: ElementProperty[];

    constructor(http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
        http.get(baseUrl + 'api/ElementProperties').subscribe(result => {
            this.Properties = (result.json() as ElementProperty[]);
        }, error => console.error(error));
    }
}

interface ElementProperty {
    Id: number;
    ElementId: number;
    Name: string;
}
```

It doesn't :(

Only when I change the interface ElementProperty to use lowercase first letters, and of course change all references to same, does it work.

I guess I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a setting I can use to make the json() adhere to
   translation definition or at least create a translator? (It's
   unclear if this is only the first letter...I'll investigate that
   further)
2. Why does it do this?

Comment: It's likely because your returned data has attributes "id", "elementId", and "name", but not "Id", "ElementId", and "Name". Note that, for instance, "id" and "Id" are different and unrelated from each other as far as the program is concerned.

Comment: What kind of error does it throw? Did you try using `IHttpResponse< ElementProperty>` for the response type? That could eliminate the need for the cast.

Comment: @realharry - Thanks for the quick reply. That's kinda what I thought would be the logical answer. Unfortunately the class defines the case of the returned data, so I can't see how the returned data can be anything else but what the class defines. Unless you are seeing something I am not.

Comment: @fodma1 - The error is that it can't read a property of a null object. I confirmed an object was been returned and saw the generated json was a different case. Once I changed the case of the interface, the component field Property was initialized and I could successfully render the html page values.

Comment: @drmssst _"so I can't see how the returned data can be anything else but what the class defines."_ I think you are misunderstanding. What the server returns has very little to do with what you define on a client side (unless they were deliberately designed to match). Take a look at the returned json data (e.g., by logging).

Comment: @realharry - Excellent now we are on the same page. That's exactly what I discovered, that the returned data was lowercase first letters. The call to the server is returning objects of class ElementProperty. Hence my expectation it would still be as defined by the class. I'll add the ASP.NET controller that reflects this.

Comment: I think you are still misunderstanding. _"The call to the server is returning objects of class ElementProperty. Hence my expectation it would still be as defined by the class."_ You CANNOT change what is returned by the server. You can ONLY USE it, as is. (What is `ElementProperty`? Is something the server provides you with? Then, they have a bug.) Seems like you are thinking that you can force/coerce the returned data to your desired type. But, that's NOT how it works. You define your type BASED ON WHAT THE SERVER SENDS TO YOU.

Comment: hmmm...The server is what is returned from ASP.NET controller. The controller sends a reply of type IEnumerable<ElementProperty>. ElementProperty is a Model and defined as described in the question. I agree that it should be only used as it is. Therefore my surprise that the returned data from the controller, before initializing value looks like this like "[object Object]: {_body: "[{"id":1,"elementId":1,"name":"Instruction"}]", headers: Object, ok: true, status: 200, statusText: "OK"...}"

Comment: Aha. there might be something going on that I am not fully aware of. (It's been a while since I did any ASP.net programming.) In .Net, the convention is that the property names are capitalized. In some other languages, that's not the case. Is there a rule/convention that we need to follow when we use ASP.net as a backend? I don't know/recall.

Comment: @realharry - Yes that's pretty much where it stands. The only thing I can think of is that the httpGet is returning the JSON formatted value in terms of its own rules.Thanks for the replies and discussion.

Comment: @drmssst Just to add to that, IF there is a "problem", it's really a server issue. ASP.net might have an option/config to change the case of property names (just a wild guess) when they generate a json payload. (I highly doubt that the client http library is changing the json data.) As far as the client is concerned, I think you need to parse based on the actual server json data/format (lowercase) rather than what ASP.net type/interface dictates (capitalized property names).

Comment: I had the same issue and found the following discussion on GitHub: 
[link](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/194)

The point is to use this line in your ConfigureServices method:
`services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());`

And of course load `Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: I have moved this comment to an answer, since in my opinion, it is the answer to the original question.*

---

I had the same issue and found the following discussion on GitHub: [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/194).

The point is to use this line in your `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = 
               new DefaultContractResolver());
```

And of course load `Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;` too.

Comment: Thanks for the promising solution. Let me try that and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution. If you know why the other json parser did what it did (or have an opinion about the behaviour) please share. I'm very grateful for the solution.

Comment: As an aside, something I'm researching now, the change has had a side effect. Now I get the following error message found in console (even though page loads correctly) `SCRIPT5: SCRIPT5: Access is denied.'

Comment: To close the loop on this. It appears the error historically is constrained to IE9 (tho I encountered on Edge). After fixing some issues on another Controller. This error went away on Edge. It never appeared on Chrome. I came back here to state/confirm that the solution doesn't appear to have a negative side when environment only has this change.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. In Chrome and I haven't seen this error either. It is seemingly related to the "protected mode" of IE (security zones), but I do not know why IE finds it insecure.

Comment: Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson after services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {
                options.UseMemberCasing();
                options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();

                options.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
                options.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
            }); the problem solved.